# I have different result if pass same argument why?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing some GUI apps in java. I wonder why JFrame.setBackground(Color) and Graphics.setColor(Color) return differ result on screen although I pass the same Color variable?

I create JPanel. It set as JRootPane with setBackground(new Color(0xB7CBEF)). JPanel has a button which draw with overload paintComponent. Inside methode I call Graphics.setColor(0xB7CBEF))..Graphics.fillRect(0,0,button_width, button_heigth). On screen background of button look at little be dark.

Thanks all. Problem was in realize external UI, which some dark background of button in passive condition. Fix this problem with transform button to transparent type.

Comment: Please show some code, tell us what you're expecting and what happens instead.

Comment: OK enough jokes, please provide more details like some code?

Comment: `JFrame` contains a `JRootPane`, which contains the content pane, calling `setBackground` on a `JFrame` only sets the background of the frame itself, try using `JFrame#getContentPane#setBackground`...this is also why it's normally discouraged to paint directly to a frame ;)

Comment: I create JPanel. It set as JRootPane with setBackground(new Color(0xB7CBEF)). JPanel has a button which draw with overload paintComponent. Inside methode I call Graphics.setColor(0xB7CBEF))..Graphics.fillRect(0,0,button_width, button_heigth). On screen background of button look at little be dark.

Comment: Code fragments in comments are hard to read; please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.